# How to: Use source installed version of Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have ROS kinetic installed with gazebo_ros and all but I have to modify the simulator in order to skip [this error.](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2068/directional-friction-still-broken)

How can I use the newly source copiled version of Gazebo 7?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16631/how-to:-use-source-installed-version-of-gazebo/) by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

you should be able to just install gazebo and export the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly so that the source install version is used. If you build gazebo in a catkin workspace then sourcing the workspace setup file should take care of the paths.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) on 2017-07-07**:
Thanks for the answer. this would work if I am trying to use ros with it? I need to use gazebo_ros, which uses the default version and I don't know how to override it.

**Comment by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) on 2017-07-07**:
That worked, thanks. So my question is answered but I still have to find out how to spawn my robot in there because I cannot for now.